# What may be confusing using lower letter class names?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

We all know that most applications out there assume class names to follow the PascalCase naming convention. We also know that it doesn't really matter what convention you follow, you should just stick to that.

I really hate CamelCase and PascalCase for everything. My personal conventions are:

```
function_name()
$var_name
CONST
method_name()
$this->property_name
```

So I thought, why don't use `class_name` and `name\space\class_name` instead of `ClassName` and `Name\Space\ClassName`?

The only confusing part is when you do `$a = new class_name()` but you clearly see that `class_name` is a class and not a function.

What might fall into confusing? What may be worse than any other naming convention?

Comment: "We all know that most applications out there assume class names to follow the PascalCase naming convention" "What might fall into confusing?" I think you answered your own question.

Comment: Try exaggerating the question 100 times and you'll see the answer: "I really hate the syntax of PHP so I invented this new preprocessor. Function parameters are now put in front of the function name, and `$` was replaced with `:` because it's easier to type. Since there are no ambiguities in this new language, how could it possibly be confusing to fellow programmers?"

Comment: @Martin, I think I got the concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy about it, please do so, but I would get annoyed really soon if I had to type `class_` all the time.

If you're talking about weird conventions, why still write consts in capitals. I never understood this. You want a value alright, why should it matter if it's a define, a class constant, a variable or even a function?

That said, conventions are there, so everyone can read each others code more easily. If I know that all class names start with a capital, using a capital for each next word in their name, I get confused if I start using your code along with that other code, because it follows different conventions.

So it doesn't matter which convention you use, as long as it's the one everybody uses. :)

Comment: In my case it is necessary to have upper case letter constants otherwise `random` could be both a class and a constant.

Comment: Than make up another name for either one.

Comment: And by the way `class_name` was just an example. I didn't mean you have to prefix all the classes. A class declaration example would be `class index extends controller {}`.

Comment: Then you got naming conflicts between classes and functions too. ;-)

Comment: "The only confusing part is when you do $a = new class_name() but you clearly see that class_name is a class and not a function.".